# Multiprocessing multiple images using Rekognition in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, python-multiprocessing, amazon-rekognition

I am trying to detect labels of multiple images using AWS Rekognition in Python.
This process requires around 3 seconds for an image to get labelled. Is there any way I can label these images in parallel?

Since I have restrained using boto3 sessions, please provide the code snippet, if possible.

Comment: Have you got a begin of code? We are here to help find a solution, not to code ii for you.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is, instead of running your code in local machine, run it in the cloud as a function. With AWS Lambda you can do this easily. Just add s3 object upload as a trigger to your lambda , whenever any image will be uploaded to your s3 bucket , it will trigger your lambda function and it will **detect_labels** and then you can use those labels the way you want, you can even store them to a dynamodb table for later reference and fetch from that table.

Best thing is if you upload multiple images simulataneously, then each image will be parallely executed as lambda is highly scalable and you get all results at same time.

Example Code for the same :

```
from __future__ import print_function

import boto3
from decimal import Decimal
import json
import urllib

print('Loading function')

rekognition = boto3.client('rekognition')


# --------------- Helper Functions to call Rekognition APIs ------------------





def detect_labels(bucket, key):
    response = rekognition.detect_labels(Image={"S3Object": {"Bucket": bucket, "Name": key}})

    # Sample code to write response to DynamoDB table 'MyTable' with 'PK' as Primary Key.
    # Note: role used for executing this Lambda function should have write access to the table.
    #table = boto3.resource('dynamodb').Table('MyTable')
    #labels = [{'Confidence': Decimal(str(label_prediction['Confidence'])), 'Name': label_prediction['Name']} for label_prediction in response['Labels']]
    #table.put_item(Item={'PK': key, 'Labels': labels})
    return response



# --------------- Main handler ------------------


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Get the object from the event
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'].encode('utf8'))
    try:
        #Calls rekognition DetectLabels API to detect labels in S3 object
        response = detect_labels(bucket, key)
        print(response)

        return response
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("Error processing object {} from bucket {}. ".format(key, bucket) +
              "Make sure your object and bucket exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.")
        raise e
```

Comment: may be necessary to keep in mind the Rekognition Service Quota Limit. In some region the Rekognition DetectLabels API TPS limit is 50(u-east-1) , 5(ap-south-1) etc. Meaning the maximum number of concurrent DetectLabels API calls per account is the TPS limit (50 or 5 etc. based on your region). Thus you may need some kind of request buffering to avoid breaching quota limit.